# Issue with nunit test runner

Tags: nunit, .net-4.5

Unable to run nunit tests Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 v17.4.0
with

```
  <package id="NUnit" version="3.13.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NUnit3TestAdapter" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

throws

NUnit Adapter 4.3.0.0: Test discovery starting
Exception System.UnauthorizedAccessException, Exception thrown discovering tests in ***\Debug\Communication.dll
Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\InternalTrace.11604.log' is denied.

How to solve it

Comment: This is a known bug. Version 4.3.1 is to be released this week. You can find a pre-release here: https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/files/9965427/NUnit3TestAdapter.4.3.1-alpha.111.zip